# After create - why does it not return relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When creating an entry using create() - Why does it return a relationship of  `pilot_id` table instead of just showing the value of `pilot_id`?

For example, in the repository class:

```
public function createFlight()
  $flight = App\Flight::create([
     'name' => 'Flight 10'
     'pilot_id' => 4
  ]);

  return $flight;
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function show()
{
   $data = $this->flight->createFlight();
   return $data
}
```

It would return json on the screen but it is not showing the relationship table (`pilot`) of pilot_id.

Comment: Because that's what you're returning in variable $flight. You saved the Flight model and you return it. You're not indicating anywhere that you want to return the relationship as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your Flight model, like so.  By default you need to tell Laravel to include any relationships.

```
protected $with = ['pilot'];
```

That will make it so everytime it includes the relationship.  If this is not desirable, then you will want to load the relationships when you return the flight, like so.

```
return $flight->load(['pilot']);
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows `pilot_id` is `4` because that's what its value is. Did you create a [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) on the `Flight` so that Laravel knows how to retrieve the model for `Pilot`? It should look something like this:

```
public function pilot()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Pilot');
}
```

When you return a model directly from the controller, it invokes the `toJson()` method to convert the object to a string. If you want to append the contents of a related model you can do so by adding the relationship to the `$with` variable on the `Flight` model.

```
protected $with = ['pilot']
```